# Need help modelling a question that appears to be an expected value question but isn't

Tags: probability

I'm playing a game right now, and one of the formulas for damage they have is:

Your character has 11 equipment slots. Let's call it head, neck, body, back, hand, hand, ring, ring, arm, waist, leg. Your goal is to find out how to maximize your damage. The "formula" for damage is as follows:

You have 1100 "total" points of damage. Assume you can assign these points of damage in increments of 100 to any number of equipment slots. Each equipment slot has a 10% chance of dealing its assigned damage value to the enemy. However, only 1 equipment slot will ever be able to deal damage, meaning if even 1 piece of equip deals damage, the damage rolls for the other pieces of equipment is 0.

To illustrate extremes, I can decide to allocate 1100 points of damage to head, or evenly distribute 100 points of damage across all pieces of equipment. I can also decide to allocate 500, 500, and 100 to head, neck, and back, respectively.

What's the best point distribution to maximize my damage?

Comment: Hi! This is somewhat underspecified (and also a bit unclear). Primarily, one needs to know how to arbitrate collisions. Let's suppose that both head and hand deal damage. Which one "wins out"? ¶ Aside from that, I'm having a conceptual problem understanding what's going on. Your character has $11$ equipment slots. One of them is head. Does that mean the head is equipped with something that can deal damage? And so on for the other $10$ slots?

Comment: Also, are you trying to maximize the expected damage, or the probability of dealing more than some threshold of damage, or what?

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that the maximum expected damage occurs when you put all 1100 points in one slot. If multiple slots could deal damage at the same time, the expected damage would be 110 no matter how they were distributed; but in every case where points are assigned to more than one slot, that expected value is reached only because two slots can combine damage. Ergo, all assignments that use two or more slots have expected value less than if you put it all in one slot.

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's assume it if the very first one that shows up.

Comment: @DavidK this was the answer that was given to me as well, but I can't see why this is obvious to some.

Comment: @BrianTung you're trying to maximize damage.

Comment: @Mezzoforte: I get that all the time. ¶ That's still unclear, though. If one strategy has a $20$ percent chance of doing $500$ damage versus a $10$ percent chance of doing $800$ damage, which one is preferred?

Comment: The question is fundamentally flawed but it's hard to explain why in a comment if it's not already obvious to you. So I've posted an "answer" that actually does partially answer the question but also shows why this question cannot be completely answered as written.

Answer (score 1):

> Each equipment slot has a 10% chance of dealing its assigned damage value to the enemy. However, only 1 equipment slot will ever be able to deal damage, the damage rolls for the other pieces of equipment is 0.

If we take this literally as written, it says that there is a $10\%$ chance that the head deals damage and no other slot deals damage. There is also a $10\%$ chance that the neck deals damage and no other slot (including the head) deals damage.

Obviously these two events are mutually exclusive. So are the other nine events for each of the other nine slots, each of which has a $10\%$ chance of occurring according to what you wrote.

But you can't have eleven mutually exclusive events, each of which has $10\%$ chance of occurring. The probabilities of mutually exclusive events have to add up to $100\%$ or less, and $11 \times 10\% = 110\%$.
Therefore what you wrote cannot literally be the rules of the game.

So you must have meant something else. We can only guess what.

A reasonable guess is that there is something -- let's call it a "hit" -- that occurs for each slot with probability $10\%$ independent of whether any other slot also has a "hit". Then if more than one slot with a non-zero number of damage points assigned to it has a "hit" there is a procedure to decide which of those slots deals the damage.

Then if you assign $1100$ points to one slot, with probability $10\%$ that slot has a "hit" and no other slot with non-zero points does, so you deal $1100$ damage.
The expected damage dealt is therefore
$$ 1100 \times 10\% = 110. $$

Now suppose you assign non-zero points to each of two or more slots.
Suppose slots $i$ and $j$ are two of those slots.
Then the probability that at least one of the slots $i$ and $j$ has a "hit"
is $19\%$. It's less than $20\%$ because there's a $1\%$ chance you have a "hit" with both of these slots. But the event that you deal damage from slot $i$ is mutually exclusive with the event that you deal damage from slot $j$.
So at least one of these slots has less than a $10\%$ chance of actually dealing damage.

Now that we have established that at least one of the slots that has damage points assigned has less than $10\%$ chance to actually deal that damage, we can say something about the expected damage. Suppose we have assigned non-zero points to $n$ slots, and let's number those slots $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$.
Let $d_i > 0$ be the damage assigned to slot $i$ and let $p_i$ be the probability that slot $i$ actually deals damage (and no other slot does).
Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n d_k = 1100
$$
and the expected damage is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n d_k p_k.
$$

Since we know that at least one of these slots has less than $10\%$ probability to deal damage, let slot $m$ be such a slot. That is, let $p_m < 10\%$.
Since $p_k \leq 10\%$ for every $k$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n d_k p_k &= d_m p_m + \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ k \neq m}} d_k p_k\\
&\leq d_m p_m + 10\% \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ k \neq m}} d_k\\
&< 10\% d_m + 10\% \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ k \neq m}} d_k\\
&= 10\% \sum_{k=1}^n d_k \\
& = 110.
\end{align}

That is, the expected damage is strictly less than $110$ and this strategy is worse than putting $1100$ points on one slot.

---

Note that I made no assumptions about how we decide which slot actually deals damage when the $10\%$ event occurs for two or more slots.
The only assumption is that you can't assign non-zero damage to two slots and have both of them have a $10\%$ chance of actually dealing its damage
(that is, neither slot will ever "cancel" the damage of the other slot).

Conceivably you could have some kind of joint distribution over the slots after assigning the damage so that there is more than one slot with non-zero damage and a true $10\%$ chance of **actually** dealing that damage.
I don't think you have any such scheme in mind but it's possible to rig one up. But no such scheme can assign every slot a true $10\%$ chance of actually dealing damage. So the strategy then is to put the $1100$ points only on slots that have a true $10\%$ chance of actually dealing damage and to put no points on any other slots. This achieves an expected damage of $110$, which is the maximum possible.

---

For a more specific answer, you would need more specific rules about how the "$10\%$ chance" is determined for each slot and what happens when two or more slots simultaneously succeed at whatever it is that has the "$10\%$ chance".